# tikzpicture graph does not compile

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I am new here at tex.se and looking for some help.

For a project I have to automatically compile some given Latex strings, that I can not change. However I can add some headers or define some new commands.

Does someone know what packages I need to add so this certain lines will compile in that way?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[graph]
  \node[graph node] (1) [label=above:\(1\)]{};
  \node[graph node] (2) at ($(1) + (-36:1.5cm)$) [label=right:\(2\)] {};
  \node[graph node] (3) at ($(2) + (-108:1.5cm)$) [label=right:\(3\)] {};
  \node[graph node] (4) [left of=3, label=left:\(4\)] {};
  \node[graph node] (5) at ($(1) + (-144:1.5cm)$) [label=left:\(5\)] {};
  \node[graph node] (6) at ($(2) + (15:2.0cm)$) [label=left:\(6\)] {};
  \node[graph node] (7) [right of=6, label=right:\(7\)] {};
  \node[graph node] (8) [below of=7, label=right:\(8\)] {};
  \node[graph node] (9) [below of=6, label=left:\(9\)] {};

  \path[->]
    (2) edge (1)
        edge (3)
        edge (5)
    (3) edge (1)
        edge[bend left=10] (4)
    (4) edge (1)
        edge[bend left=10] (3)
        edge (5)
    (6) edge[bend left=10] (7)
        edge (8)
        edge (9)
    (7) edge[bend left=10] (6)
        edge (8)
    (9) edge (8);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I have already some packages included like:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
```

But I do get this error:

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/graph' and I am
>   going to  ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: I guess that the problem lies in `\begin{tikzpicture}[graph]`. Somewhere `graph` must be defined. Try to compile it without `[graph]`.

Comment: that is somehow the problem. I have to remove all 'graph's in the example in my code, but I think it would be easier not to. Can I somehow implement a dummy definition. And how would I do that?

Comment: "Search and Replace"?! (text editor functionality)

Comment: The tex-file does get assmbled by a java code, that until now just appends all tex-strings without caring about whats inside. I do now that the strings compile with the source-template, but I do not know  how the source-template looks like. Is it that hard to define a dummy "graph" notation?

Comment: Creating a dummy graph style can be done by `\tikzset{graph/.style={}}` before all the tikzpictures.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Well, this compiles and gives output.  Note that the `tkzgraph` package has its own distinct setup: consult [its manual](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-graph/doc/tkz-graph-screen.pdf) before using it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (1) [label=above:\(1\)]{};
  \node (2) at ($(1) + (-36:1.5cm)$) [label=right:\(2\)] {};
  \node (3) at ($(2) + (-108:1.5cm)$) [label=right:\(3\)] {};
  \node (4) [left of=3, label=left:\(4\)] {};
  \node (5) at ($(1) + (-144:1.5cm)$) [label=left:\(5\)] {};
  \node (6) at ($(2) + (15:2.0cm)$) [label=left:\(6\)] {};
  \node (7) [right of=6, label=right:\(7\)] {};
  \node (8) [below of=7, label=right:\(8\)] {};
  \node (9) [below of=6, label=left:\(9\)] {};

  \path[->]
    (2) edge (1)
        edge (3)
        edge (5)
    (3) edge (1)
        edge[bend left=10] (4)
    (4) edge (1)
        edge[bend left=10] (3)
        edge (5)
    (6) edge[bend left=10] (7)
        edge (8)
        edge (9)
    (7) edge[bend left=10] (6)
        edge (8)
    (9) edge (8);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As I told in the comments above I do not want to edit the latex string. So tried  marsupilam solution and it worked. But thank you anyway :)